# TypeError: PermissionsBitField is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

after consulting the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#displaying-permission-flags)  I wrote this code:

`const {PermissionsBitField} = require("discord.js"); console.log(new PermissionsBitField(8n).toArray())`

in theory i should print in console: ["administrator"]

bat doesn't work the error is:
TypeError: PermissionsBitField is not a constructor.

I am using discord.js v13.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `PermissionsBitField` does not exist in v13 - there's another class called `Permissions`. If you need to use v13, then refer to the [v13 docs](https://v13.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#roles-as-bot-permissions) or upgrade to newer version.